# Shouldn't TypeScript complain about me assigning a wrong type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Consider the following code: ([playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRycYYUwARgK6QCMAXMgM7mgDmA3AcSWRTUgAmJqwoguBAL4ECYAJ4AHFACE4UHD2Kk2giIxZsJ3fDPwEE6EK2QA3OABtqEZsiYYsAXhx9dtfUwARAAWEA4O6IEANL4C-iLIgQDu6FAOACaByGaW1mB2js7MQm7Iahre9k4uJrnM6A4QAHQR7AAUVUVCAJQmBEA))

```
interface Foo {
    attribute1: string;
    attribute2: string;
}

type Bar {
    attribute1: string;
}

const values : Foo = { attribute1: "hello", attribute2: "world" }
const values2 : Bar = values;
```

It's clearly recognizable at compile time that `values: Foo` has more properties than `values2 : Bar`. Yet I can assign `const values2 : Bar = values;`. Shouldn't TypeScript complain about this? Is  my understanding of `type` wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal behavior in Typescript, what the compiler will do for you is when assigning values to values2, it will check if the variable values has a field called attribute1 of type string and that's it, it won't check if values has other fields, i hope I made it clear for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Until now I really was under the impression that Typescript would do more for me ):

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf This isn't really much different to interfaces in e.g. Java, where just because something has type `List<String>` doesn't mean it can't have other members too. The only difference in this regard is that in Java a class only implements an interface if it says it does, whereas in Typescript a class (or object) conforms to an interface if it does have the properties declared in that interface (which your `values` does).

Answer (score 1):

You hoped for [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) to happen more often in TypeScript.

Excess property checks do exist in TS, but only happen when **directly giving a type to an object literal**.

So in your example, `values2` indeed shows no TS error:

```
type Bar { attribute1: string; }
const values : Foo = { attribute1: "hello", attribute2: "world" }

const values2 : Bar = values;
```

But when I write the `values` object directly as an object literal (a comma-separated list of name-value pairs wrapped in curly braces) without first storing it in the `values` variable, I do get a TypeScript error for adding the `attribute2` property which I didn't explicitly define in the `Bar` type:

```
type Bar { attribute1: string; }

const values2WithWarning : Bar = { attribute1: "hello", attribute2: "world" };
```

The TS error:

```
Type '{ attribute1: string; attribute2: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'attribute2' does not exist in type 'Bar'. Did you mean to write 'attribute1'?(2322)
```

I updated your [TS playground with the new line](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=28&pln=10&pc=31#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRycYYUwARgK6QCMAXMgM7mgDmA3AcSWRTUgAmJqwoguBAL4ECYAJ4AHFACE4UZAF4cfNoIiMWbCZ2Qz8BBOhCtkANzgAbahGbImGLNuy6BtA0wARAAWEI6O6IEANL5U-iLIgQDu6FCOACaBZpbWtg7OrkLuyGoa2vkuzNz4VjZg9k6VQgDqwGDBzeogHMWlWjqkev6GIWER0bH6CcmpGVlS1bI1ueiOEAB0EewAFBWFAJTVQA).